# Как сделать проверку изображения по нажатию клавиши

Tags: java

Есть код, где по нажатию на клавишу space должно провериться изображение и, исходя из того, какое оно, выполниться нужный метод.

Правильно ли мыслю? И возможны ли вообще в джаве такие вот вложенные условия?

```
if (key == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {

    if (изображение 1) {
        right();
    }

    if (изображение 2) {
        left();
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

То, что находится в скобках условного оператора, должно возвращать true/false. Так что вам вероятно придется написать как-то так:

```
if (isImage1(изображение 1)) {
    right();
}
```

Если картинка у вас как уникальная сущность, чтобы не писать по методу на каждую можно сделать так:

```
int getImageCode(изображение) {... return imageCode;}

void doSmth() {
  if (key == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
    int imageCode = getImageCode(изображение);
    switch (imageCode) {
      case 1: right(); break;
      case 2: left(); break;
      default: right();
    }
  }
}
```

.. а сами коды хранить в Enum.

Вкладывать можно сколько угодно, но если условный оператор имеет много ветвлений, лучше подумать о полиморфизме.

Comment: Попробовал сделать, как Вы предложили в 1-м примере, создал boolean методы, которым на вход передал переменные изображений, в своем условии расписал все, как Вы сказали, но на space теперь реагируют все методы сразу. 
Логику менять пока не хочется, может что-то не так пишу?

       if (key == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
    
   if (isImageRight(manRight)) {
    
    fireRight();
    
   }
   
   if (isImageLeft(manLeft)) {
    
    fireLeft();
    
   }
   
   if (isImageUp(manUp)) {
    
    fireUp();
    
   }

   if (isImageDown(manDown)) {
    
    fireDown();
    
   }
  }

Comment: Значит все ваши 4 условия возвращают true. А должно по видимому только одно из них. Ищите ошибку в isImageXXX.